# Calibration Curve Scikit Learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, calibration

Can anyone explain that scikit learn calibration curve plots which two quantity against each other? I did not exactly understand what is the meaning of Fraction of positive. [image]

Answer (score 1):

In the example, it is about a binary classification problem, where the two possible classes are often called a positive and a negative class. A positive class can have several meanings. For example, in biomedical sciences, a positive case is often a person with a certain disease. Or, when a researcher is interested in whether someone has a diploma or not, having a diploma is Positive, not having a diploma Negative. One might be interested in whether a photograph includes a person: photographs with a person are Positive, photographs without a person are Negative.

As stated in the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/calibration.html), a classifier is well-calibrated if the predicted probability represents a class membership probability. That means: if the predicted probability of the positive class is 40 percent, the true fraction of the positive class is also around 40 percent. In terms of an example: if the predicted probability of heaving disease D is around 40 percent, the expected fraction of people with disease D is around 40 percent.